# Converting from decimal to binary digits upto n bits

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am converting decimal numbers to n binary bits, then separate it into n binary bits and then assign it to x by x grid.

For example:- 325 -> 101000101 -> 1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1

I have written the following code, please help me figure out what algorithm shall I use for this task. Thanks!

```
int binary_num[100];
int separate_num[100];

    for (int i = 0; i<pow(2,4); i++) {
        int j = 0;
        int n = i;
        while(n>0) {
            binary_num[j] = n%2;
            j++;
            n /= 2;
        }
        for (int k = j-1; j>=0; j--) {
            int h = 0;
            separate_num[h] = binary_num[k];
            h++;
        }

    }


return 0;
```

Comment: `int binary_num[] = {};` is an empty array. Are you sure that the compiler accepts it? Even if it does... What do you want to store in an empty array (with 0 elements capacity)?

Comment: Not an answer, but why dont you use `std::bitset`

Comment: ...or `std::vector`?

Comment: As usual in these questions, there is no decimal to binary conversion here. You are converting binary to printable binary. Not the same thing.

Comment: The binary number array should store in the binary number upto n bits. I am not sure, how to store only uto n bits in that array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] (preferably one that we can copy-paste and replicate your problem without any editing or modifications) and [edit] your question to show it, together with a *detailed* description of the problems you have with it

Comment: Do you want to define `n` beforehand or do you just want an array where `n` is just big enough to store the binary number without leading `0`s?

Comment: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cd16c8322abe20c) (Please, note the conversion to `unsigned` which is necessary to let the right-shift work as expected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bitset to find the required number of bits and you can store it in array then print in grid